# Async function sends a response before await returns a result

Tags: express

I have a function that creates JWT-tokens and set them as cookies. I use this function in my login controller right before I send a response to a client. The problem is the controller sends a response before set-JWT-as-cookies function is finished.

**controller**

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ username }).select("+password");

    if (!user || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        return res.status(401).json("wrong_credentials");
    }

    await jwtHelper.createTokens(user._id, res);

    console.log("right before sending a response", Date.now());

    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        data: {
            role: user.role,
        },
    });
});
```

**createTokens function**

```
exports.createTokens = catchAsync(async (userId, res) => {
    const accessToken = createAccessToken(userId);
    const { tokenId: refreshTokenId, token: refreshToken } = createRefreshToken();

    await Token.create({ tokenId: refreshTokenId });

    const accessCookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
    };

    const refreshCookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() +
                process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
    };

    console.log("right before creating cookies", Date.now());
    res.cookie("access-token", accessToken, accessCookieOptions);
    res.cookie("refresh-token", refreshToken, refreshCookieOptions);
    console.log("right after creating cookies", Date.now());
});
```

And that's what I get in a console

```
right before sending a response 1631544430242
[1] right before creating cookies 1631544430324
[1] (node:11224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

How do I set cookies before sending the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `catchAsync`, the `createTokens` function returns immediately even though it involves the asynchronous `Token.create`. After it returns, `res.json` is executed, and `res.cookie` comes only later, after the `Token.create` has also finished. This leads to the error.

The following illustrates this:

```js
const {catchAsync} = require("catch-async-express");

async function f() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }).then(() => console.log(1));
}

async function g() {
    await catchAsync(f)();
    console.log(2);
}

g();
```

`2` is logged immediately, and `1` is logged after the 1000ms timeout.

Avoid using `catchAsync` here.

Comment: I suggest you drop the `catchAsync`.

Comment: btw I dropped catchAsync and it worked!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I feel that this behaviour should be documented on the npm page for `catch-async-express`.